# postgresql - How to return null values in NOT IN expression

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a column which can contain values from **1 to 6** and **null**..

Then when I try to run the query below.. rows with null value on that column do not return

```
select * from customer where Position not IN  ('1','2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6')
```

Is there way I can retrieve null results without adding this on above query

```
OR Position is null
```

Comment: The answer is: No. (But why a condition checking for all possible values?)

Comment: I created a system where user can select NOT IN condition then he will indicate the values.

Comment: For example in above query... users select NOT IN condition then he input the values 1,2,3,4,5,6.. that's why I arrived on that kind of query

Comment: Why are you storing (or comparing) numbers as strings?

Comment: each number, 1-6 , has corresponding name saved in the system..

Comment: ..so instead of displaying the full position name, we assigned ID on each position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick you could use would be to coalesce the position to some value which does not appear in the restricted list, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE COALESCE(Position, '9') NOT IN  ('1', '2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6')
```

However, I would probably just use an `is null` clause here:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE Position NOT IN  ('1', '2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6') OR
      Position IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there way I can retrieve null results without adding `OR Position is null`

There are plenty of ways, but `OR Position is null` is the easiest, the shorteste and the most natural way.

If you don't like it, then there are few ideas below:

```
select *
 from customer where ID NOT IN (
  select ID
    from customer where Position IN  ('1','2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6')
);


select *
 from customer where
 1 = CASE WHEN Position IN  ('1','2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6')
          THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;


select * from customer c
left join (
    SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6]) x
) x
ON c.position = x.x
WHERE x.x IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the `NULL` result then include that as a condition in your `WHERE` clause else *NO* it's not possible

```
select * from customer 
where Position not IN  ('1','2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6')
or Position is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition : `Position IS NULL`

```
SELECT    *
FROM      Customer
WHERE     Position NOT IN  ('1','2', '3', '4' ,'5', '6') OR Position IS NULL
```

You can see this here => http://rextester.com/HEZ87754

Hope this helps!!!